# Append Folder name with current date in LFTP

Tags: lftp

I am trying to create a directory with current date **(like  BK-date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M" )** in `ftp` remote site using LFTP `mkdir` command, but I am unable to create.

please provide some suggestions how I can able to achieve this.

Example:

```
mkdir -p /backup/BK-date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use “source -e date +‘mkdir %…’”